# Paylpal integration with other static libraries not working

Tags: ios, paypal, static-libraries

I am using multiple static libraries in my project and I am trying to use Paypal SDK but getting linker error(duplication of symbol) as for paypal we have to set -lstdc++ and -ObjC in other linker flags.When i am removing all of my libraries it is working and if i remove -ObjC project is running but crashing when calling paypal. Any idea why can't I set -ObjC when using static libraries in our main project? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i resolved it by setting -force_load "full path of paypallib.a" in other linker flags by this we will force our library to be loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `-lc++`? If so, try removing it. There's [a known issue](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK/issues/2) around this that will be resolved in an upcoming release.